# Evaluate parameter in class constructor

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'd like to achieve two things after creating an instance with an object as parameter:

First, iterate over the properties of the parameter and add it to the instance, if it is **exactly** the same type as this property way declared above the constructor. Is there a quick way to do so are do I have to check this one by one?

Secondly, i want to check if each of the declared properties is defined and set a default value if not.

```
var data = {
  langs: ["de","en","fr"],
  lesson: {
    de: "Einführung",
    en: "Introduction"
  },
  keywords: []
}

class Video {
  langs: Array<string>;
  lesson: object;
  topic: object;
  intro: object;
  keywords: Array<Keyword>;

  constructor (data) {
    for (let prop in data) {
      if (/*data.s is of type as declared above constructor()*/) {
        this[prop] = data[prop];
      } else {
        throw "Type of {{prop}} is invalid";
      }
    }
    for (let prop in /*All the props defined above constructor()*/) {
      if (!this.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
        //Set default value;
      }
    }
  }
}

var video = new Video(data);
```

Comment: No, there's no way to do neither of what you asked for. The reason is that both the property names and their types are lost after the compilation process. You'll need to save that information as part of the code, either yourself or with decorators (metadata)

Comment: You can do this, but it requires some extra inspection. Arrays for example ar of type Object.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a quick way to do so are do I have to check this one by one?

Use a type annotation e.g. change

```
constructor (data) {
```

To

```
constructor (data: { langs : string[] /* so on */}) {
```

> i want to check if each of the declared properties is defined and set a default value if not.

Use strictNullChecks to move the logic out of your code : https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/options/strictNullChecks.html